# How to resolve "API Error code 4202" error while Facebook share using mobile web

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Iam developing a web application using mvc. In my application iam using facebook graph api to share something to facebook. I had done it with javascript.
My code is

```
    var fbResponse;
    var code = $("#c_Test").val();
    if (code) {
        url = url + "/" + code;
    }
    FB.init({
        appId: appId,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.0'
    });
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log(response);
            var fbResponse = response.authResponse;
            FB.ui(
              {
                  app_id: appId,
                  method: 'send',
                  link: url
              },
              function (response) {
                  if (response) {
                  } else {
                  }
              }
            );
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                $("#c_Name").val(response.name);
            });
        } else {
        }
```

Its works perfects in desktop web browsers. While using my application in iphone iam getting an error like

> API Error Code: 4202
>   API Error Description: This dialog can not be displayed on this device
>   Error Message: This method is not supported for this display type.

How can we solve this api error ? please help me

Comment: Hey, did you solved this problem? I have the same issue with the difference that instead of using javascript, I stub everything in a href of a button, should work the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace your following code:

```
method: 'send',
```

with following code:

```
method: 'feed',
```

For help regarding fb feed method follow fb link given below

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

One more thing you missing for send menthod here is `According to fb There is no response data from this dialog` so your code is not according to documentation aswell.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

**Edit**

May be this will help, just remove fllowing code from your above code.

,

```
function (response) {
    if (response) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to share the link to private as private message ! can you help me to send the link as message ?

Comment: I have functionality for sharing the content as private message and also functionality for share to my wall in facebook. Share to wall works in all devices but send private message doesn't works in mobile devices.

Comment: because when you sending in private message by send method then remove response code, because there is no response for send method.

Comment: Iam  taking response from login, after login iam calling send methos. Its working in desktop browsers. The issue with only iphone.